# Setting up VisualPHPUnit with CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

It looks like the web test runner test.php was removed in CakePHP3 - and from what I can find, the suggestion to replace it is https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit.

(source: https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/12)

I am having trouble getting VisualPHPUnit set up so that it properly runs the tests in CakePHP3, and I can't seem to find the tutorial section that was intended to be written as mentioned in the above link.

Can anyone provide a tutorial, or pointers/suggestions for setting up VisualPHPUnit alongside a cakephp3 app, or as a plugin?

Comment: I'd like to understand the reason why you prefer running tests in a browser instead of the commnand line

Comment: Why fuss with it.. stick with command line.

Comment: Come on now... don't take the easy out of telling me to use the command line.  Obviously that is an option, but it isn't my preference in this case.  The old web interface (test.php) for running tests provided many benefits (easier navigation of tests, code coverage visuals, etc.) - and in this case Mark is even suggesting VisualPHPUnit, and apparently intended to add instructions for it to the cake book.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm trying to understand your reasons, not because I'm saying they are invalid. Regarding the code coverage, have you ever tried generating the code coverage in the console? I think it is several times better than the coverage that used to be generated in the test.php file

Comment: I guess I am confused why you are leading me away from VisualPHPUnit, which is suggested to be used with CakePHP3?  Is there some issue with using it?

Comment: There is no where in the documentation where using  VisualPHPUnit  is suggested. That was an idea in the days that the test.php file was removed. That project seem to have stalled and depends on older versions of phpunit.

Comment: Here's where VIsualPHPUnit is suggested in the CakePHP 3.0 documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#testing